# VUE project just run on the error

Tags: vue.js, frontend

[image]

Why the new VUE project just run on the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not exactly errors but warnings. You can choose to ignore them or resolve them. Your console looks fine and is running properly.

Comment: However, when I visit it, it is a blank page instead of vue the welcome page